# Xcode 4.3.3 crashing consistently after opening workspace in xc4.dp4

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

Lion, Xcode 4.3.3, and vex code 4.5 dp4

After creating a new local git branch to specifically avoid this type of problem, I'm unable to open a critical production workspace with xcode 4.3.3 after having opened it, in another branch, with xcode 4.5pd4. I also tried cloning from origin again, as I haven't pushed to remote since opening the workspace in 4.5, but I'm unable to open that version of the workspace either. No matter what I do, Xcode 4.3.3 crashes soon after launching. What can I do to reset, delete preferences, whatever, to get 4.3.3 working again?

Comment: Pull the Plist for xcode and restart.

Comment: thanks for the reply; not sure I understand your suggestion. Can you elaborate a bit more? Thanks again

Comment: Most if not all apps in OSX have a plist file where it stores preferences and other small things, you can drag it out of containting folder onto desktop and restart the computer. The app will auto genterate a fresh plist with default preferences, fixes alot of issues on osx, particulary crashing.

Comment: Usually its stored in: Select Macintosh HD -> Users -> [USER YOUR LOGGED IN AS] -> Library -> Preferences. Find com.apple.xcode.plist, when you do this for the OSX mail program it deletes your mail accounts, so it may delete some things you dont want it to, but could fix crashing

Comment: yeah, not something I would recommend here. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting this for completion purposes

I had to have inadvertently opened the workspace on the incorrect branch at one point; it's the only thing that makes sense. I noticed that after opening it under 4.5 again, all my xib's were defaulted to an incorrect compatibility in IB, and after manually adjusting them all to proper values using the current tools versions and making sure none were set to use a new, feature (that I'm not naming here due to NDA purposes) I was once again able to open the workspace under both 4.3.3 and 4.4.